# Create a transparent color in PDF

Tags: pdf, colors, transparency

I'd like to create a transparent color in PDF (directly, no external software). I know for example with `x y z rg x y z RG` I can set the rgb color values for stroking and non-stroking operations. How do I create a transparent color? A link to the correct search terms in the pdf spec would be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transparency in PDF is a property of objects, not colors ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#Transparency)).

The Wapedia contains a [description of the PDF file format](http://wapedia.mobi/en/Pdf). See Section 3.2.4. for "details" on transparency. Like all other resources on the web, they are mostly superficial.

I suggest to use a tool from Adobe to create the four forms of transparency and examine the result.